# Integrality of integral polytope?

Tags: nt.number-theory, convex-polytopes

Given a convex polytope with integral vertices presented in half-space description is there a way to test in

1. polynomial time or
2. polynomial hierarchy

if polytope has integral volume?

Finding volume to desired approximation is in $PSPACE$.

Comment: If it helps, $(\dim P)! \operatorname{vol}(P)$ is necessarily an integer

Comment: @AviSteiner Denominator has to be smooth integer and so related to diophantine approximation? Could you clarify your comment? To be integral denominator has to be $1$. Perhaps there is something here.